# Cuda_Error_Illegal_address on 3090 RTX

Tags: rendering, gpu, error

Hey I have a problem with blender, when I want to render one scene.
And the scene is pretty small, the only one big thing in there is a 16k hdri.
But my PC Specs should easy handle it.

Could someone say what that error means?
CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS in cuStreamSynchronize(cuda_stream[thread_index]) (device_optix.cpp:821)
[image]

PC Specs:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10900KF CPU @ 3.70GHz   3.70 GHz

32,0 GB RAM

3090 RTX 24GB

Comment: Do you by any chance use linux and have used blender after a resume from standby? Does this error occur also wenn running blender immediately after a fresh boot?

Comment: no I use windows 10 and yes it does

Comment: Are you using the gaming or studio version of the NVIDIA drivers and are they up to date?  The studio version is preferred for blender because it has fewer bugs.

Comment: I use the studio version